# If $c$ is the only real solution of $f(x) = 0$ then prove that $c$ is the only hyperreal solution.

Tags: real-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

> If $c$ is the only real solution of $f(x) = 0$ then prove that $c$ is the only hyperreal solution.

---

I can't see how this is a valid question since we can have $c + \delta$ as a solution to $f^*(x) = 0$ and since $st(c+ \delta) = c$ we still have $f(c) = 0$ as only real solution.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from transfer: it's true that $$(\exists c)[\ ^*f(c) = 0 \wedge (\forall x)(^*f(x) = \ ^*f(c) \to x = c) ]$$
if and only if it's true that $$(\exists c)[f(c) = 0 \wedge (\forall x)(f(x) = f(c) \to x=c)]$$

We could identify an infinitesimal if your theorem were true: if there were $\delta$ with $\delta \not = 0$ such that $^*f(c) = \ ^*f(c+\delta) = 0$, then we could identify $\delta$ as $(c+\delta) - c$. Since it's not possible to distinguish "strictly nonstandard" reals from standard reals without referring to the standard universe, there must either be both standard and nonstandard $\delta \not = 0$ making $\ ^*f(c+\delta) = 0$, or there must be no $\delta \not = 0$ with $^*f(c+\delta) = 0$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to read that arrow ?

Comment: "Implies", if you meant $\to$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You can use `$\implies$` to make implies arrow.

Comment: There is a difference between how I use the two arrows, but I'm struggling to express what that difference is. I think the essence is that I use \to in a logic context in sentences, and \implies if I'm linking actual statements I'm making about maths.

Comment: @Patrick: Maybe, $\to$ is a proposition and $\implies$ is an assertion?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d$ is another hyperreal solution to $f(x)=0$. Then we have two distinct hyperreal solutions $c$ and $d$, which we can summarize by the formula
$$\exists x \exists y [(x\not=y) \wedge (f(x)=f(y)=0)].$$ Then by *downward* transfer we get that the same formula holds over $\mathbb R$, so that $c$ is not a unique real solution. The contradiction proves the uniqueness of solution in the hyperreals, as well.

Comment: Yes thanks, I thought of transfer principle, but I did not know that I can use its converse.

Comment: Glad to help!  When you start learning *infinitesimal analysis* (as opposed to *infinitesimal calculus*) you will find out that this equivalence is an important underlying principle called *elementary equivalence*. Thus, the hyperreals are elementarily equivalent to the reals.

Comment: I will first complete this book and then try to learn real NSA. Thank you for all the help.